# EMR GetAutoTerminationPolicy error when destroying the resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

I am getting below error when destroying EMR resource in AWS gov cloud using Terraform

**│ Error: error getting auto termination policy: UnknownOperationException: Could not find operation GetAutoTerminationPolicy**
The reason this error happening is because terraform is always looking for AutoTerminationPolicy on the resource when it is trying to refresh the state from the resource. But in Gov Cloud AutoTerminationPolicy is not available for EMR.

> [Auto-termination for idle clusters using an auto-termination policy is not available in AWS GovCloud (US) Regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-emr.html#:%7E:text=Auto%2Dtermination%20for%20idle%20clusters%20using%20an%20auto%2Dtermination%20policy%20is%20not%20available%20in%20AWS%20GovCloud%20(US)%20Regions.).

It looks like bug on the terraform side. Any option to go around this error and have the destroy work.

Please share any insights on this. Thanks for looking into it.

Regards
SN